# Multiple custom post types showing up in edit.php

Tags: custom-post-types, admin-menu

I'm having a bit of trouble (i think) over custom post types in Wordpress.

I have created multiple post types and they all work, but there is this one thing which is bothering me.

Lets say I have 3 custom post types. Movies, Albums and Video Games, each one of them has a set number of posts.

Now, in the sidebar menu i admin, if I click on Movies' "All Movies" it shows the most recent entries, regardless if its movies, albums or video games..

Is there a way to to separate them, so when I press "All Movies", it only shows posts in post type Movies?

I might add that I have used [smashing's guide](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/08/complete-guide-custom-post-types/) to creating custom post types.

Here is an example of the code I used to register a post type:

```
function post_type_movies() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Movies', 'post type general name' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Movie', 'post type singular name' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'Movie' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Movie' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Movie' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Movie' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Movies' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Movie' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Movies' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No Movies found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Movies found in the Trash' ), 
        'parent_item_colon'  => '',
        'menu_name'          => 'Movies Post',

    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'description'        => '',
        'public'             => true,
        'menu_position'      => 30,
        'supports'           => array('title','editor','thumbnail', 'custom-fields'),
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-portfolio',
        'post_tags'          => true,
    );
    register_post_type('movie-post', $args);

}
add_action('init','post_type_movies');
```

Here are other post types for comparison:
// Post Type - Games

```
function post_type_games() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Games', 'post type general name' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Game', 'post type singular name' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'game' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Game' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Game' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Game' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Games' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Game' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Games' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No Games found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Games found in the Trash' ), 
        'parent_item_colon'  => '',
        'menu_name'          => 'Games',

    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'description'        => '',
        'public'             => true,
        'menu_position'      => 40,
        'supports'           => array('title','editor','thumbnail', 'custom-fields'),
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-welcome-widgets-menus',
        'post_tags'          => true,
    );
    register_post_type('game', $args);

}
add_action('init','post_type_games');
```

// Post Type - Locations

```
function post_type_locations() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Locations', 'post type general name' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Location', 'post type singular name' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'book' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Location' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Location' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Product' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Locations' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Location' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Locations' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No Locations found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Locations found in the Trash' ), 
        'parent_item_colon'  => '',
        'menu_name'          => 'Locations',

    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'description'        => '',
        'public'             => true,
        'menu_position'      => 30,
        'supports'           => array('title','editor','thumbnail', 'custom-fields'),
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-location',
        'post_tags'          => true,
    );
    register_post_type('location', $args);

}
add_action('init','post_type_locations');
```

Comment: Can you share a link with the code you used to register the custom post types? Community would do a better work helping by providing that.

Comment: Sure, I used this [guide](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/08/complete-guide-custom-post-types/) by smashing magazine

Comment: What you want, if I understand you, is how it is supposed to work. Something is wrong with your code or something else-- plugin, theme-- is causing trouble. What do the **other** CPT registrations look like?

Comment: @TheTimeRanger so from my understanding of your question, no matter what post type you're on it always shows `Movie` Posts? Have you tried disabling all plugins and switching to the default theme?

Comment: The important part is `register_post_type('movie-post', $args);` where there different names for the post type are necessary. If those are different I'd suggest disabling all plugins to see if the issue persists.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Not exactly. What's happening is that no matter which of the post type I click on, it shows me all of them. Latest first. I.e If I'm on `Movies` it will also show `Video Games` and `Albums`

Comment: @TheTimeRanger I suggest searching the theme for a `pre_get_posts` filter. If you can't find it disable all plugins, if it still persists, register your `post-types` on the default Twenty-Fifteen theme, if it still persists re-install WordPress, if it still persists report back here. There isn't anything ( that I know of ) when register the post type that could cause that sort of behaviour. If I were a betting man, I'd say there's a malformed `pre_get_posts` somewhere.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Updated the question to show the others.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee You sir, just pointed it out! I have this `function pregp_archive_ppp_wpse_108225($qry) {
  if ($qry->is_main_query() && $qry->is_archive()) {
      $qry->set('posts_per_page',5);
      $qry->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'location', 'game' ) );
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','pregp_archive_ppp_wpse_108225');` in order to allow my archive page to display all post types... i tried removing it and it totally solved it!! Now, I just have to fix the archive page lol. Thanks! How do I give you a mark for solving it?

Comment: @TheTimeRanger one second, you're missing a single conditional, i'll write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `pre_get_posts` runs on both the Front End and on the Admin Side unless you specifically tell it not to, here's the function you supplied with a small twist:

```
function pregp_archive_ppp_wpse_108225( $qry ) {
    if( is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }

    if( $qry->is_main_query() && $qry->is_archive() ) {
        $qry->set( 'posts_per_page', 5 );
        $qry->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'location', 'game' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'pregp_archive_ppp_wpse_108225' );
```

Note the first conditional [`is_admin()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin) - this will test against any / every admin page so that the following changes will only apply to front-end queries.

Comment: Thank you so very very much @Howdy_McGee. You solved two issues I had in one go! Thank you, i'm quite new to Wordpress development, so I still have many things I have yet to learn!